# Pandas reads almost every column in .txt as index - SOLVED

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a file named "sample name_TIC.txt". The first three columns in this file are useful - Scan, Time, and TIC. It also has 456 not useful columns after the first 3. To do other data processing, I need these not-useful columns to go away. So I wrote a bit of code to start:

```
os.chdir(main_folder)
mydir = (os.getcwd())

nameslist=['Scan','Time', 'TIC']
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('TIC.txt')):
            myfile=os.path.join(path, file)
            TIC_df = pd.read_csv(myfile,sep="\t",skiprows=1, usecols=[0,1,2],names=nameslist)
```

Normally, the `for` loop is set into a function that is iterated over a very large set of folders with a lot of samples, hence the `os.walk` stuff, but we can ignore that right now. This code will be completed to save a new .txt file with only the 3 relevant columns.

The problem comes in the last line, the `pd.read_csv` line. This results in a dataframe with an index column that comprises the data from the first 456 columns and the last 3 columns of the .txt are given the names in **nameslist** and callable as columns in pandas, (i.e. using `.iloc`). This is *not* a multi-index. It is a single index with all the data and whitespace of those first columns.

In this example code `sep="\t"` because that's how excel can successfully import it. But I've also tried:

1. `sep="\s"`
2. `delimiter=r"\s+"` rather than a `sep` argument
3. including `header=None`
4. <strike>not including the `usecols` argument</strike> **I made an error, and did not call the proper result from this code edit. This is the correct solution. See edit below or the answer.**
5. setting `index_col=False`

How can I get pd.read_csv to take the first 3 columns and ignore the rest?

Thanks.

EDIT: In my end-of-day foolishness, I made an error, changing the target df to the example `TIC_df`. In the original code set I took this from, this was named `mz207_df`. My call function was still referncing the old df name.

Changing the last line of code to:

```
TIC_df = pd.read_csv(myfile,sep="\s+",skiprows=1, usecols[0,1,2],names=nameslist)
```

successfully resolved my problem. Using `sep="\t"` also worked. Sorry for wasting people's time. I will post this with an answer as well in case someone needs to learn about `usecols` like I did.

Comment: are you sure that your `txt` file is tab separated ? `\t` indicates that the columns in the file are separated by tabs, can you share a sample of that file ?

Comment: 1) How you know the last row in the txt is the issue? 2)does it contain any data? 3)if you are 100 percent sure it is the last row and it contains nothing essential, can you delete it? If so you could try If you know the error comes from the last row, why not deleting it? ```lines = file.readlines()``` and then ```
lines = lines[:-1]```

Comment: Jimmar - the ```\t``` was chosen because, when importing it into Excel, tab delimiting works and comma or whitespace doesn't. But I have tried the using ```\s+\``` (which normally works for files from this analytical machine). I will try to share a sample file. 

Serge - that's my fault on communication. The last line of the example *code* generates the problem, not the last row of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Answering here to make sure the problem gets flagged as answered, in case someone else searches for it.

I made an error when calling the result from the code which included the `usecols=[0,1,2]` argument, and I was calling an older dataframe. The following line of code successfully generated the desired code.

`TIC_df = pd.read_csv(myfile,sep="\s+",skiprows=1, usecols=[0,1,2],names=nameslist)`

Using `sep="\t"` also generated the correct dataframe, but I default to \s+ to accomdate different and varible formatting from analytical machine outputs.